# How to write XPath code to customize a sorted list of data in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sorting, sharepoint, xpath, designer

Hello to all and thank you for any help!

I am working within a data form web part in SharePoint Designer and I need to sort the data in a fairly abstract way. It needs to be sorted by one column alphabetically but the catch is that there are two specific values from another column that have absolute priority and belong at the top of the list. I am brand new to the XPath language. Can I get a hand with some XPath code or a direction to take to solve my problem?

-Philip

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath to sort the results in a custom manner after the server has delivered them is not going to be very efficient; it's better to have SharePoint sort the results via CAML query parameters before it returns them to you so that you can work with the paged results. Otherwise you'll be looking at retrieving every item from the list just to put them in the right order.

You might consider taking a different approach that spares you from writing custom XSLT. Depending on the column type that drives your sort order, you may be able to add a calculated column to the list that displays a modified version of the source column's value.

The following formula checks if a column named "Source Column" is equal to "Value A" or "Value B". If it's one of those values, it'll display the value preceded by "1. " or "2. "; otherwise it'll display the value preceded by "3. ".

`=IF([Source Column]="Value A","1. "&[Source Column],IF([Source Column="Value B","2. "&[Source Column],"3. "&[Source Column]))`

Here's a quick matrix of what the calculated column's value would be for various inputs:

```
Source Column | Calculated Value
  "Value A"   |  "1. Value A"
  "Value B"   |  "2. Value B"
  "Value C"   |  "3. Value C"
"Other Value" |  "3. Other Value"
```

The goal here is not to display the value of this calculated column, but to sort a view by it.

The end result is that items where [Source Column] is equal to "Value A" or "Value B" will on the top, while the rest of the items will be sorted in alphabetical order.